# EXCEL 2013 auto reference to new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to reference a new column as current data in my formula.

Formula: `=E3 * 2%`

Then when I add a new Column in front, the formula changes to: `=F3 * 2%`

How do I keep the `E3` from changing even if I add a new Column in front of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid INDIRECT. Try,

```
=index(3:3, 1, 5)*0.02
```

This goes through row 3 and returns the value from the 5th column. With the 5 hard-coded into the formula, it will not change due to column insertion or deletion.